# Invalid host header error as I try to deploy a react heroku app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

I am trying to deploy a simple react application on heroku. As I deploy I see an error `Invalid Host header`. I cannot understand the reason for this. To prevent this error I created a `.env.development` file in the root and added:

```
HOST=fce-bxxok-3517.herokuapp.com
```

but as I do this I still get an error saying `Could not find an open port at  fce-bxxok-3517.herokuapp.com/`.

What could be the reason for this?

This is how my `package.json` looks like:

```
    {
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "latest",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.0"
  },
  "name": "9n6m1",
  "description": null,
  "version": "0.0.303",
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "1.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am fully not able to understand the issue but it looks like somewhere you are hard coding the value of the port which should not be done. Heroku automatically assigns a port to the app.

Also, if you want to just host the react js app on any server, you can use **NETLIFY** which will help you deploy your app in a lot easier way because it is actually built for it. Heroku is mostly used for deploying server-side apps like Python, Flask, Ruby.

Comment: Thanks bud... You saved a lot of time. `NETLIFY` is great.